# Grails using Geb from its downloaded source

Tags: grails, intellij-idea, geb

I am using Grails 2.2.3, seleniumVersion = "2.27.0", spockVersion = "spock-grails-support:0.7-groovy-2.0", geb = "0.9.2", on windows 7 (unfortunately not my choice)

When I run a dependency report there are no errors. Running a full build the only issue I get is with geb:

```
   |  geb.driver.DriverCreationException: failed to create driver from callback 'script13855910667632068403539$_run_closure2_clo
sure4_closure5@65ed1a6b'
        at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:35)
        at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver_closure3(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:80)
        at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory$SimpleCache.get(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:30)
        at geb.driver.CachingDriverFactory.getDriver(CachingDriverFactory.groovy:79)
        at geb.Configuration.createDriver(Configuration.groovy:354)
        at geb.Configuration.getDriver(Configuration.groovy:343)
        at geb.Browser.getDriver(Browser.groovy:105)
        at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:394)
        at geb.Browser.go(Browser.groovy:386)
        at support.FunctionalSpec.setupSpec_closure1(FunctionalSpec.groovy:13)
        at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:860)
        at geb.Browser.drive(Browser.groovy:830)
        at support.FunctionalSpec.setupSpec(FunctionalSpec.groovy:12)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
        at script13855910667632068403539.run_closure2_closure4_closure5(script13855910667632068403539.groovy:60)
        at geb.driver.CallbackDriverFactory.getDriver(CallbackDriverFactory.groovy:29)
        ... 12 more
```

In Intellij IDEA Ultimate 12.1.6 it just works.

My last resort as this is preventing local runs of the full-build, is to use geb as a downloaded plugin (inline plugin seems tricky because of gradle), and compare the two contexts to see what is wrong with the command line one.

Can anyone share some pointers as to how to get geb plugin picked up from my machine?

I tried http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/plugins.html#12.1%20Creating%20and%20Installing%20Plug-ins "Specify plugin location" but because of Geb's modular structure it does not work : "Cannot find plugin descriptor for path 'C:\projects\geb'

Comment: Can you explain what `full-build` means to you?

Comment: It is a groovy script that just runs all my tasks, for instance clean, jslint, codenarc, unit tests and then functional tests with Geb. Sorry for the unnecessary confusion, I should have said functional testing , that is "grails test-app functional:"